# parent div gets pushed by child, creates gap in parent div

Tags: css, nested, css-position

I have my main div, inside that one I have another div and inside that one I have another div. What Im trying to do is get the last div to "float" outside of both of its parents, its a badge that I want to have sticking out of the main div. This doesnt work how I want it tho, the main div gets expanded but the background color doesnt even cover those pixels, I can see the background of the body behind it!

Heres my code:

```
#main {
    background-color: #000;
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 840px;
    padding: 20px 60px 20px 60px;
}

#nested1 { 
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    }

#nested2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: -80px;
    }
```

Comment: Oh I should mention that this only happens in firefox! chrome, explorer handles this how I want it to but firefox on the other hand..

Comment: can you show some html/create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: yeah here is the link to the full html and css: http://jsfiddle.net/ZF8qP/6/

Answer (score 0):

The #main div won't expand unless there's some content inside it to make it stretch, so that sounds like the first problem. (The bit of background you are seeing is due to the padding on the #main div.)

If you want #nested2 positioned in relation to #main, it's better to give position: relative to #main than to #nested1.

Without seeing your whole setup (e.g. HTML) this is a bit of a guessing game. Could you post your whole page code, or a test page on a site like jsFiddle?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can have a look at the whole html and css here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZF8qP/6/

Comment: Aw, don't make me search all through that code to work out which bit is which. Which is the inner2 div there?

Comment: sorry man, I shouldve let you know which divs I was referring to. Its #main that gets stretched, #topMain is the nested div and inside that is the #giftsAndPromos that Im trying to move outside of the #main div. I actually have two divs I want to do this with, #twitterBird is the other one..

Comment: OK, without images loading it's not easy to understand the issue. The #giftsAndPromos part seems to be sitting to the right. This would be much easier with a live link.

Comment: someone helped me to find out what the problem was; The outline added the the extra space, I changed it to border and voila, no more gap! awesome :) \